# Is it better to handle logged in user data server-side or client-side?

Tags: laravel, rest, api, vue.js

I'm building a stateless REST-based app with JWT auth. I can get (question relates to `GET` requests) all the users posts by implementing a variable server side that takes an ID parameter passed from the client:

http://example.com/api/v1/posts?user_id=1

```
$q = $q->where('user_id', '=', $data['user_id']);
```

Or, I could check the user ID server side, and create a new route to get only the logged in users posts:

http://example.com/api/v1/me/posts

```
$q = $q->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user->id());
```

When would I use each approach and why?

Comment: Security related things are best handled at the server side, where you have the least number of loop holes. Client side, there is always greater risk of getting exposed to the security data.

Comment: Good point! Technically this data will also be available publicly, so if someone was to change the user_id passed to the server it's ok (albeit useless) for them to get someone else's posts. Furthermore, I still have to use the first method on Profile pages that show other users posts. With `create` or `put` requests I always user the server side approach.

Comment: When ever you use REST based urls for getting information, you will be sending the authenticated user information by appending that to the header right?

Comment: Yeah, but only a JWT token and App key. So I don't necessarily have access to the user_id client side, meaning I'd have to do another request to get the users data. But I could do that once and save it in Store (I'm using Vue - probably similar for other frameworks)

Comment: Yes, when you have the auth token already present in the client side, you will just need to pass it on to the server as part of the REST call. The rest of the things will be handled at the server side. This is how usually the things are done.

Comment: Yup - which describes the second approach. But I could also do one request with token to get the logged in user-id from the server to the client, and then I could do the first approach as described in the question.

Comment: @Michał as I said in my answer this will depend of the level of access that you want for give a user to `Post` resources. If you want a user to only access his/her posts then you should call `http://example.com/api/v1/me/posts` and you get the user information from the token sent in the call and then return his/her posts, this will be the best approach. Now if you want your app to show not only the logged-in user posts but also posts from other users, then you should go and use the first approach.

Answer (score 1):

This will depend of the level of access that you want for give a user to `Post` resources.

The first approach is give the any user the ability to access to resources of ANY user, for example:

- Tweets of a Twitter public user.
- Posts made by an author in a public magazine
- etc

The second approach is often used when yo want to restrict a user to only see his/her resources. For example:

- To see or edit his/her profile.
- Access historic data (like order details, likes, invoices)
- etc

Protecting endpoints this way to prevent of user A modify or access content that he/she may not have permission to make/see.

The use of any of those approaches will depend of the use case.